# How to import Celery app in Django app-level task?

Tags: django, celery

I follow the guide http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html but I can't find how to import celery app in app-level tasks.py, where it is used like this:

```
@app.task()
def do_my_task():
```

Comment: you mean top level project celery configuration to app level ??

Comment: I mean app level:
app/
    tasks.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @shared_task decorator lets you create tasks without having any concrete app instance, which is a simpler API to use than `task`.

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: how about: from celery import task ?